# ASP NET MVC - 403 Forbidden Access is Denied

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-web-app-service, ws-federation

On a team project, ASP.NET Web API MVC is used only because of WsFederation protocol and it hosts an Angular build.
The project have a Custom DelegatingHandler which it's used to call our Backend (Angular web doesn't call API URL directly, it calls "itself" so the DelegatingHandler can call our Backend)

The whole build is deployed in an Azure AppService and it works fine :) (the WsFed provider interface displays and after authentication, the Angular webapp also displays).

[image]

But sometimes I encounter a "beautiful" "403 - Forbidden Access is denied" which seems not to be related to the backend (no logs in Application Insights). Seems if I clean the cache and/or cookies, it's working again......but in PROD environment they sometimes encounters this issue and it's a little embarrassing :S

Any ideas what would be the problem ? And what to add in web.config to make it talk more :p ?

Here's a sample of my web.config (I omitted some code related to Angular Routes, or application settings):

Web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.2" />
    <httpModules>
        <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>

<location path="FederationMetadata">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>

<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <clear />
            <add name="X-XSS-Protection" value="1; mode=block" />
            <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <handlers>
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
        <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
        <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
        <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
        <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler" />
        <add name="WSFederationAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.WSFederationAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlMode="DisableCache" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
      <remove fileExtension=".json" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

There's also a web.config in Views folder but I didn't touch it (it was the one generated by default)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found myself why I had this problem
=> for those who may be in the same situation, it was WAF rules (World Application Firewall) defined in Azure that caused a 403 Forbidden

Comment: Hi we are running into same situation, would you share a bit more if you still remember? We are not using WAF but still sometimes it goes to 403.